# What are 'Low-level parameters' in bayesian analysis?

Tags: bayesian

I'm reading Kruschke's book "Doing Bayesian Data Analysis" and on the page 245 it says:

*In typical hierarchical models, the estimates of 
**low-level** parameters are pulled closer
together than they would be if there were not a higher-level distribution. This pulling
together is called shrinkage of the estimates.*

Could anybody explain the meaning of low-level and high-level parameters in bayesian analysis, please?.

I couldn't find it's definition in the book.
English is not my native language, maybe for you it's easier to understand.

Regards.

PD:
I think...
if the likelihood function can be factored like this: p(D|a,b,c) = p(D|a) p(a|b) p(b|c) p(c)
then a is a lower-level parameter than b which is a lower-level parameter than c.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer, "If the likelihood function can be factored like this: p(D|a,b,c) = p(D|a) p(a|b) p(b|c) p(c) then a is a lower-level parameter than b which is a lower-level parameter than c." is exactly correct.